# Stackdriver log quota warning - 5GB limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

We recently noticed this in our log viewer for our app-engine flexible apps.

> You have 12 days left in your Stackdriver Premium trial. Your logs usage is 5.96 GB month to date for this project. An ingestion quota of 5 GB per month will be enforced starting 12/5/16 for all projects not in the Premium Tier. Please upgrade to the Premium Tier before the trial expiration to continue ingesting all logs.

What we don't understand is, do we need to do anything? Will google just be trimming out old logs past 5GB, or will logging stop all together?

We can't seem to find anywhere where we can configure our logging peferences.

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from [this article](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#exempt-logs):

> Each log in Stackdriver Logging is classified as exempt or non-exempt.
>
> Exempt logs do not count toward your monthly logs allotment and do not
>   have overage charges if you have exceeded your allotment. The
>   following logs are exempt:
>
> - All GCP Admin Activity audit logs.
> - GCP Data Access audit logs from Google BigQuery.
>
> Non-exempt logs count against your monthly logs
>   allotment and any overage charges. All logs not listed as exempt are
>   non-exempt.

That being said, 5 GB per project is monthly allotment for non-exempt logs on Basic Tier service . Logs received over the allotment incur additional charges.

For more information visit [this article](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing).